# Hiding non-clicked rows using .siblings().hide()

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code to collapse non-clicked rows in a Bootstrap accordion table, but instead it hides the whole row of the siblings not just the `td`.

```
$('tr.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().hide();                                  
});
```

Comment: Well, the `siblings()` of a `tr` are the other `tr`... so I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen. Also note you have two `{` in your code, which I assume is just a typo in the question

Comment: _hides the whole row_.....well you just authored in that way. `$(this)` belongs to the clicked `tr`. yet this won't hide the clicked tr but siblings `tr` if there are any.

Comment: provide the html so we can help you

Comment: thanks,well the main problem with this table is that we are trying to collapse other open rows so user just have one <tr> to deal with.

Comment: Your code is doing that though, is it not?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not unfortunately,although i was expecting accordion function would do that by itself(closing other expanded rows)but it is not.I tryed other options like .{accordion:false} and etc from jquery ui .non of them give the right ouput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently most people have problem with applying this function on bootstrap tables as rows will show/hide twice either with hide/show or slideUp/Down,
so we changed the code to this:

```
$('tr.table-rows').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('open-row')){
      $(this).next('tr').fadeOut(600);
      $(this).removeClass('open-row');
    }
    else{
      $('.open-row').next('tr').fadeOut(600);
      $('.open-row').removeClass('open-row');
      $(this).next('tr').fadeIn(600);
      $(this).addClass('open-row');
    }
  });
```

now it works fine,